# file upload fails on cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Using cordova File-Transfer plugin I try to upload an image.
But upload fails.
My code looks like below.

```
function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        uploadPhoto,
        onFail, 
        {quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI}
    );
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    console.log(imageURI);
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    var userid = '123456';
    var imagefilename = userid + Number(new Date()) + ".jpg";
    options.fileName = imagefilename;
    options.mimeType = "image/jpg";
    var params = new Object();
    params.imageURI = imageURI;
    params.userid = '1';//sessionStorage.loginuserid;
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/video/upload.php";
    //console.log('sd');
    ft.upload(imageURI, url, win, fail, options, true);
}
function win(r) {
    console.log("Image uploaded successfully!!");
}
function fail(error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log("There was an error uploading image");
}
function onFail(message) {
    console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is in backend,? go through https://gonzalo123.com/2013/10/28/taking-photos-with-a-phonegapcordova-application-and-uploading-them-to-the-server/ and it will help you

Comment: backend is php. which is running on my local server.

Answer (score 0):

ok then your code should be like following:

**JavaScript:**

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

function clearCache() {
    navigator.camera.cleanup();
}

var retries = 0;
function onCapturePhoto(fileURI) {
    var win = function (r) {
        clearCache();
        retries = 0;
        alert('Done!');
    }

    var fail = function (error) {
        if (retries == 0) {
            retries ++
            setTimeout(function() {
                onCapturePhoto(fileURI)
            }, 1000)
        } else {
            retries = 0;
            clearCache();
            alert('Ups. Something wrong happens!');
        }
    }

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.params = {}; // if we need to send parameters to the server request
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://host/upload"), win, fail, options);
}

function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhoto, onFail, {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
    });
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

**PHP**

Make php file on server side my side i was using xampp php so i put my php file in `c:/xampp/htdocs` and start apache from `xampp cotrol pannel` then i make this line as `encodeURI("192.168.1.124/uploadfile.php")`

**uploadfile.php**

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], '/path/to/file');
?>
```

Ping comment if you have any confusion.

Comment: Using this code "Ups. Something wrong happens!" message shown in alert message.

Comment: try with small size image first

Comment: I tried with an image size of 12kb. But same things happens.

Comment: you need to call service with ip address only localhost won't work

Comment: then it's not an file upload error it's error because php is not connected that localhost service. find out for that or if you can debug you will get error also please update your question with that error so we can help you..

Comment: there will be error code in your console please update that error code in question for more efficient help..

Comment: Error code meanings: 1 = FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR , 2 = FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR,  3 = FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR,  4 = FileTransferError.ABORT_ERR,  5 = FileTransferError.NOT_MODIFIED_ERR

Comment: I added "console.log(error);" in fail section. It showing error code 1.